# How to detect context menu disappearance?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I need to make a control with popping out menu and button that causes it to be displayed and has changed (pressed) appearance during the time popped out menu is visible.

Currently i am using check box with Appearance property set to button and context menu. However detecting a moment when menu disappears from any reason other then click on one of its items (which generates Click event that can be handled) - for example, when the form is clicked - wasn't successful, as "Collapse" event didn't occur. As a result, "down-arrow button"  didn't change its appearance back as intended.

How can disappearance of ContextMenu be detected? What are conditions for "Collapse" event to occur?

P.S. On related note, i was trying to implement the same thing with listbox set as top level window before; when form was clicked, it changed appearance but the loss of focus didn't occur. Any help with detecting the moment when it occurs would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [ContextMenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip.aspx) you can handle the Closed event which is raised when the menu is closed.

*"How can disappearance of ContextMenu be detected? What are conditions for "Collapse" event to occur?"*

The `Collapsed` event is only raised of the ContextMenu is set as the ContextMenu of a control before you call `Show`

Comment: Thank you. It does contain functionality i need, although i am still greatly interested in answer to my original question - for the case i ever need to write drop-downs from the ground.

Comment: Ah. That explains a lot. I've not bound Context Menu to the control, so that it won't go up on right-button clicks.